# Git Bash- permission denied when trying to remove directory. Is there a sudo-like command for Git bash?

Tags: admin, bitbucket, git-bash

I've created a bitbucket repository and started out with this tutorial:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+Your+Git+Repo+and+Add+Source+Files

All was going well until I've cloned the empty repository, which created a folder called bb101repo, just like the tutorial asked. Then, the tutorial goes on to explain how the name of this folder is not precise enough and how we should make a new one, by a different name.

So, when I tried to remove the folder using the command rm -irf "bb101repo/"
the terminal displays this message:"rm:cannot remove directory 'bb101repo': Permission denied.

Is there a way of going sudo?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and found that when I close the IDE (Aptana in my case) I can remove the .git folder. The IDE was locking the directories and not letting the OS delete the files. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wherever you are, @Anz, thank you from the future! :)

Comment: Also was happening with me and Visual Studio 2013 where shutting down the IDE was required to be able to change between two pretty divergent branches.  This answer should be accepted.

Comment: This helps! Can't believe the problem is solved so simply. I thought it was something to do with the Registry as read from other related posts.

Comment: Same thing happened with me just now it was my editor, Atom, which has Git support built in.

Answer (score -2):

sudo rm -rf filename should do the trick

(you can be asked for your password)

to see what permissions files have you can use ls -l in the directory where your maps are stored

you can change the file permissions by using: chmod 755 in the folder u want to change if u want to do it recursive just add -R

chmod -R 755 (r-rw-rwx)

Comment: the console prints :sh.exe": sudo: command not found
Am I doing something wrong? I typed : sudo rm -rf bb101repo

This is why my question was : Is there a sudo-LIKE command for git bash?

Comment: try this in the map chmod 755 it wil change the file pemission of the folder

Comment: Looks like Cygwin. Underneath is a Windiws file system, not a Unix.

Comment: hmm Terminal is for the OSX so it is Unix Based..

i recommend you to use man chmod in your terminal to see the documentation of changing file permissions

Comment: ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , that is true, I am running Windows 7.
@Reshad what do you mean by 'in the map'?
after typing ls -l, the console writes:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 Pzn   Administ  ....some date jiberrish...
This might have something to do with the fact that I am not running this as an Administrator user on Windows, so I'll try again after re-logging.

Comment: Same story with the admin account. I've tried chmod -R 755 /bb101repo,
after which the console prints nothing. This made me think that the permissions HAVE been changed, but when I tried the rm -irf bb101repo, I get the same permission denied message.

Comment: what if you give it a 777 authorization? try that instead. so chmod 0777 and then try to remove it with rm -rf bb101repo ( have you tried to delete it with your interface instead of the command prompt? )

Comment: oh, I've managed to delete it with Explorer, no problem- put the problem is, what if, later in the tutorial, I am asked to do something else, something without an interface alternative. Removing a directory, on it's own, is no big deal. The principle problem of not having permission to do so is a big deal. 
I have tried 777- no luck. Thanks a lot, anyway :)

Comment: I would recommend against doing this procedure.  You don't want to have to do destructive actions to run your development environment.  It's better to find the root cause (for instance, on Windows, some rogue process is holding a lock on the file) than it is to be cavalier.  As a mentor taught me, you don't understand a problem until you can answer "why?" five times.